# Imported files from node modules using tilde not found in Angular 6 project

Tags: angular, npm

I have generated an Angular 6 project using the cli and installed Bootstrap 3 as a dependency via npm.
I can see bootstrap has been added to node_modules (and my IDE resolves the path just fine), but when I import Bootstrap less partials from node_modules into the less files of my project and run `ng serve` I get the following error:

> @import "~bootstrap/less/mixins"; ^ '~bootstrap/less/mixins' wasn't
>   found. Tried -
>   /Users//Documents/library-demo/src/app/styles/~bootstrap/less/mixins.less,npm://~bootstrap/less/mixins,npm://~bootstrap/less/mixins.less,~bootstrap/less/mixins.less
>   in
>   /Users//Documents/library-demo/src/app/styles/bootstrap.less
>   (line 9, column 0)

**Project structure** (under Documents/library-demo):

/node_modules

/src

---- /app

-------- /styles

------------ main.less

------------ bootstrap.less

**main.less**

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
```

**bootstrap.less**

```
@import "~bootstrap/less/mixins.less";
```

Is there anything I have to do for the ~ to be mapped to node_modules?

Comment: are you sure u have installed bootstrap 3 ? u sure .less file is there in bootstrap folder in node_modules?

Comment: Yes, I can see the bootstrap folder in node_modules.

Comment: i mean can you  spot `.less` file in bootstrap folder ?

Comment: Yes, the .less file I am importing is inside the bootstrap folder. My IDE finds it just find, it is there...just Angular doesn't find it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, worked fine before Angular 6.